# Create file object dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, file, google-chrome-extension

I have a JSON like

```
[
    {
        'vendor': 'fb'
        , 'name': 'abc'
        , 'image': 'https://dyn.web.fb.com/pp?t=s&u=91982444469%40c.us&i=1474346886&ref=0%40jQBYaJ1twLsLu%2Fdft7IMe6MH5dq4eBScL2R07o%2B%2FSaS8zQ&tok=0%40AbJxaNtftGaohWXewqv'
    }
    , {
        'vendor': 'tw'
        , 'name': 'xyz'
        , 'image': 'https://dyn.web.tw.com/pp?t=s&u=91982544469%40c.us&i=1474346886&ref=0%40jQBYaJ1twLsLu%2Fdft7IMe6MH5dq4eBScL2R07o%2B%2FSaS8zQ&tok=0%40AbJxaNtftGaohWXewqv'
    }
]
```

Now I want to read that image and create the `FILE object` (same returned from `input[type=file]`), I will send this object & that should get uploaded. So to do this I think first I need to create an image and then load it in canvas & then create the file object, so I tried to do something like below:

```
getImageFormUrl: function(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    img.onload = function () {
        // canvas code 
    }
    img.src = url;
}
```

but here I am getting `500 Internal Server` since that image is getting called as `text\plain` instead of `jpeg`

Comment: Please elaborate the question a little. You are already having  a URL, and you want to upload. Unable to catch the scenario.

Comment: All this image urls are from different hosts, so I want to read them and make a file object & will be sending that file object to server which will upload that image to our server

Comment: What is the complete error code that you got? is there anything else aside from 500?